# google app engine task queue sample

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

Currently, i try to working with task queue. But i don't see any complete sample on this matter.

So please give me some sample of task queue in google app engine, written in python.

Answer (score 3):

import:

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```

define and run:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/service', params={'user': user}, method="GET")
```

**url** is the RequestHandler that leads to the code to run in the queue

**params** can be regular url params

Answer (score 1):

The example in Google's documentation is simple but complete.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html