# Google App Engine Flex Python 3.4 - *Pull Queues* are not supported in documentation nor code examples

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-app-engine-python, pull-queue

*Using Python 3.4 Google App Engine Flex.*

Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/overview-pull) on using pull queues with Python says to "`from google.appengine.api import taskqueue`", but does not explain how to make taskqueue available to Python runtime.

They do [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) to "Easily Access Google API's from Python", where it explains how to install the api client via "`pip install google-api-python-client`"

This does not install the taskqueue lib.

From the previous doc, there is a [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine) to "Installation", where it says:

*Because the Python client libraries are not installed in the App Engine Python runtime environment, they must be vendored into your application just like third-party libraries.*

This [links](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring) to another page "Using third-party libraries", which states you need to either install a lib to /lib or use requirements.txt.  Neither of these make taskueue available.

Searching for taskqueue.py in Google's github shows only an [example module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/multitenancy/taskqueue.py) with the same name.

There is a [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue) on the module, but no information on how to install it.

There is a Python 2.7 example that google points to [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/taskqueue/counter), but it doesn't work.  There is no setup of taskqueue, no requirements.txt, no instructions.

There is a stack overflow question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848896/google-api-client-python-import-taskqueue), and the checked answer says to install the SDK.  That takes you to [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads), which takes you to [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/download), which takes you [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/download), which takes you to [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/), which provides the gcloud SDK download for deploying and managing gcloud.  This does not include the python lib for taskqueue.

There is another similar stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800885/google-app-engine-task-queue-sample), which says:
[image]
... this is now starting to feel like an infinite loop.  Yes, it's been made crystal clear you need to import the taskqueue.  But *how* do you make it available?

I've asked the question to Google Support and they haven't been able to answer for 4 days.

I've opened two issues, one [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1080) and another [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3834).  No answers yet.

Do not want to use Python < 3.4.

Do not want to use HTTP REST API.

Just want a simple pull queue.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the docs you mentioned are standard environment docs and do not apply to the flexible environment.

From the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queue) section in [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating):

> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref).
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

Comment: Thank you.  I found this https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-pub-sub, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or/45842773#45842773